# zero distance in views geofield proximity problem

Tags: 7, views, entities, location

I am having trouble getting it views to calculate the distance. I want a current user to see the distance to other users however the only result I have gotten is 0 between users.

I tried to follow this and still got no result:

> Looks pretty straightforward using geofield 7.x-2.0-alpha2:
>
> I assume you have geofield and geophp enabled and assume you have
>   added a geofield to your users that get the location from an
>   addressfield.
>
> create a view of type users add "[name of your geofield] - proximity"
>   field select "source of origin", I tried "exposed geofield proximity
>   filter", check the "round" box add "[name of your geofield] -
>   proximity" exposed filter and select a "source of origin point" as
>   well. For example, add a "geocoded location" (fancy word for address)
>   add that same field to your sort options to sort by proximity as well.
>   In your example you would probably change the "source of origin point"
>   to "current user".

I have checked the users address and they create points. Do anyone have an idea how to get it to work?

Comment: By "no result," what do you mean?  You'll need to provide more details about what steps exactly you have taken.  The original instructions as posted by MotoTribe work; I have done the same myself.

Comment: Okay, by no result I mean the proximity field in views show 0 in distance.. I followed the instruction from MotoTribe as well but when configuring the field to be proximity i can se an error in the background:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function'RADIANS' --> when/and before it is saved the distance show zero for each user

Comment: apparently there is a new realease under way fixing some bugs

Answer (score 2):

I just posted a new documentation page for geofield that shows how to setup a basic proximity search: http://drupal.org/node/1944648

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Even though it's preferable to post at least a snippet here, I'm upvoting him just appreciate his (own) great writing in d.o docs. No offense intended, @MPD

Answer (score 1):

At first I also received only zeroes in the proximity field.

I had created an addressfield field for user location, as well as a geofield field which used that addressfield to store geocoded data.

In views, I set the "Geocoded Location - proximity" settings to:
Round: [checked]
Source of Origin: Current User
Source Field: [name of geocoded user field]

Still zero; I returned to my test user page and manually entered a location (rather than relying on Smart IP/automatic geolocation) and saved the data.

I also succeeded in adding a contextual filter for User Location:
- Selected filter: Global: Null
- Selected "Provide Default Value" for "When the filter value is NOT in the URL:"
- For Default Value type, selected in dropdown menu:
Visitor location attribute (via IP Geolocation)
- For "Location attribute to use," selected "Postal Code."

After updating user data and adding the contextual filter, I received non-zero results for the proximity field.

However, deleting the filter did not change results, so I believe it was the newly-saved user data that made a difference.

Hope this helps in your troubleshooting.

Comment: you said `However, deleting the filter did not change results, so I believe it was the newly-saved user data that made a difference.` What are you trying to say?