# Geofield proximity order

Tags: 7, views, location

I would like to sort my results by proximity in Drupal 7 Views.

I have already read the [geofield proximity in views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54873/geofield-proximity-in-views) topic.

But that tutorial is using a location provided by the user (exposed filter) and I would like to use the location provided by the HTML5 API call for an anonymous user, and want to order the results by distance.

Using the "current user" as source does not work, although the page asks for location from the browser.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it working with exposed user (exposed filter)  ?

Comment: Yes, its working when exposed.